# How to make MTA:SA register pyautogui keystrokes

Tags: python, pyautogui, mta

So, the only problem I have is MTA not registering key presses made by pyautogui, what's worse, it registeres when I'm not in any server, it stops working as soon as I join a server.

I tried different methods than pyautogui but nothing works, I am sure that there is a way to make it work, it doesn't need to be in python but I want to find a way to do that.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.